# What is the format "BM6"?

Tags: image, colors, game-boy-advance

I am working with an old system of palletes. When I export an image, it also creates an pallete with 15/16 colors. But when I try to replicate the same result, the program does not recognize the image which I just created. To analyse what happened, I opened  some images with notepad and compared them with my "creation" and I noticed quite some differences.

But the most interesting thing was that at the beginning of my images' code was the type "BM6", while they should be "png" or "bmp". I think that is some thing of codification, but I cannot find anything about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the image file is properly formed, then you can take your `.bm6` file and simple change / rename the extension to `.bmp`.  And it should suddenly be an image.

`.bm6` can result from creating an image file using a text editor, [as seen here.](https://forum.cryptoworld.is/showthread.php?tid=62)

Comment: Link is broken.